# Eclipse - Show generated class files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, class

How can I show the folder (bin) where my class files are placed after I build a project in eclipse? I want this directory to show up in the package explorer. Searched the forums, but can't seem to find an answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can view the the bin folders in the `Navigator` (`Window` --> `Show View` ---> `Navigator`), **which is now deprecated**, or in the `Project Explorer` (`Window` --> `Show View` ---> `Project Explorer`) . But you can't view the bin folders in the `Package Explorer`.

For viewing the bin folders in the `Project Explorer` , you can click `Customize View` ---> `Filters` --> Do not click `Java Output Folders`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cheers. Is there a way to show this in the package explorer though?

Comment: I don't think you can view the bin folders in the package explorer ,but I find it can be viewed in the project explorer

Comment: This actually doesnt enable to show class files in "Open Resource" right ? How can I enable to show class files in "Open Resource" explorer