# eclipse doesn't see class file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipse project.

I add directory `src/directory` and put there SomeClass.java

I compile my application.

in `somedirectory` in filesystem I see `.class` file.

But in eclipse `somedirectory` looks  empty.

What the reason? How to fix it?

I press F5 many times!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

eclipse hides class files when you are in the package explorer. Try to switch to the navigator (Ctrl+3 and type "navigator") then a "bin" folder should appear and that one contains your class file.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Eclipse `src` folder and output folder that will contain the compiled classes are two different folders. These two folders' location are configured in the Project's properties page, under the *Java Build Path* tab. More information on the configuration [can be found here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm).

So when you press in F5 in Eclipse to refresh the folder, you are basically refreshing the source folder, and you will never see the `.class` file in there. The output folder that contains the `.class` files are hidden by the Project Explorer view.

If you absolutely want to see these files via Eclipse, switch to the *Resource* perspective and follow the instructions as given [by the answer of this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780182/eclipse-show-generated-class-files) or rather follow instructions given by @markusw , CTRL-3 + Navigator view is way quicker!

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy of the source directory `src`, should be the same as the package name of the classes inside it. In other words, if you have a class whose package name is `com.example.util`, then that class should be located inside the directory `src/com/example/util`.

Comment: it is true but I know it.