# Directory named "bin" not visible in my Scala IDE (Typesafe's Eclipse plugin)

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I've just created a directory called bin under my project's root node, but when I refresh the project (F5) I simply don't see it.

I want to put some *nix shells in there, so I think it is a convenient name, but I cannot get why Eclipse mustn't show a directory with that specific name in its package explorer.

Notice the project structure was created from the command line according to the template suggested by SBT.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `eclipse` command in sbt to generate the Eclipse configuration file, the `bin` folder is set as the  default output folder for the project. And Eclipse hides the output folders.

I see 2 possible solutions:

- Use the 'Project Explorer' instead, and follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780182/eclipse-show-generated-class-files) to show the `bin` folder.
- Change the default output folder for the project. In the project properties -> `Java Build Path` -> `Source`. Set the `Default output folder` to `<project_dir>/target/scala-2.10/classes`. It should be a safe default, and it will 'free' the `bin` folder.