# Maven puts class files into expected target folder but they are invisible in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am building in Eclipse (latest version) using Maven. The output class files do exist in the projects target directory, just as the log output indicates but they are invisible under target. This does not seem to be a filter problem since I do not see a way to filter out class files, only inner class files.

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior.  What do you want to do with the .class files from within eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

.class files are not visible in most of the Navigator type views in Eclipse (Project Explorer, Navigator etc).

You question title says "are visible" but in your question you say "they are invisible" - which is it exactly? By default they are always invisible - you have to go to the file system if you want to see the .class files.

Comment: This is the expected/default behavior. Why do you want to see the .class files? If you want to check they are there (check a project is actually compiling?) then drop down to the file system and take a look there?

Comment: I think there are perspectives where they are visible. Different Eclipse downloaded JEE and I do see them. So it is probably a matter of perspective or view.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780182/eclipse-show-generated-class-files

Comment: Depending on what Eclipse version, in the Navigator view, click the drop down arrow on the far right of the view window, select Filters, uncheck the filter to hide *.class - now they should be visible.