# Finding .class file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to turn in the .class file of a class from Eclipse. I managed to turn in the .java version of the file by clicking and dragging it into my browser, but I'm not sure where to find a .class file. I've read that I can find it in the "bin" but I have no idea where this is.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780182/eclipse-show-generated-class-files

Comment: Use File Search feature to get quick response. See my Answer.

Comment: Greetings Avocado, welcome to the stack. Don't forget to mark with the green check mark your accepted answer as seen here in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It reinforces the answerers, alerts people, you gain rep, and other useful things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, Eclipse projects have the following file system:

```
Proj/
   .classpath
   .project
   src/
      Foo.java
   bin/
      Foo.class
```

So, navigate to the Project folder, go to `bin`, and your classes should be right there.

**If you are on a mac:**

If you are in your project in the command line (you have done `cd project`)
You can do

```
cd bin
open .
```

And your class files should show up in a place that you can drag them into a browser.  **I don't understand why you need to submit `.class` files, as they are generated when the code is compiled.**

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise if this answer helped you, could you accept it by pressing the checkmark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

**`Ctrl + Shift + T`**

will list down all the files including **`.class`** files in all of your projects in the workspace.