# Is there a way to make Eclipse Package Explorer show output directory content?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e, package-explorer

I hate having to switch to the Navigator view just to see what was built. For example, if I want to see if my *.properties files getting moved, etc.

I tried removing all of the Filters... from Package Explorer's dropdown menu, but it is still not displaying the contents of my "target" folder.

Am I missing something?

I attached my .classpath

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only the Project Explorer view (*not* Package Explorer) can display output folders.
In that (Project) view, you should see a small down arrow at the top right of the view:

- Choose the option `Customize View` option.
- Uncheck the 'Java output folders' option in the filters list.

You would see the same process to [see `.class` files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6780182/6309) produced by a classic java build.